# Data validation with RegEx on time-formatted cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I need to validate time entered in a cell. But the cell HAS to be in date format because I will need it later to extract hours and minutes.

My RegEx will check perfectly if the cell format is plain text, but if I set it to "time" or "date" or "hh:MM", I get an error in the Spreadsheet : "Parameter 1 expects text, but 0.52154 is number type and can't be forced to text type" (approximate translation from French, sorry).

My formula :

`=REGEXMATCH(F5,"([0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])?([0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])?([0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])?([0-9]:[0-5][0-9])?")`

Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

You could convert number to text with formula:

```
=REGEXMATCH(TEXT(F5,"hh:mm:ss"),regex)
```

`hh:mm:ss` converts the number into proper sting that mimics time format.

to make sure, that entered time is in number format, you should also use ISNUMBER function:

```
=and(ISNUMBER(F5),REGEXMATCH(TEXT(F5,"hh:mm:ss"),regex)
```

will return `false` if text was entered.

Answer (score 0):

The value reads:

> Function `REGEXMATCH` parameter 1 expects text values. But '123' is a number and cannot be coerced to a text.

You get an error because a regex cannot be applied to values other than text. Cast the value to text and use the `REGEXMATCH`:

```
=REGEXMATCH(TEXT(F5,""),"([0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])?([0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])?([0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])?([0-9]:[0-5][0-9])?")
            ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not working. I've created this spreadsheet to test : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c5LYmYLQJHObnu3dDufZNetltDAPpDkbYQf19zVsP5U/edit?usp=sharing . There are several tests, none of them works. It's not a regex issue, although I hesitate to replace the ? with |, but I will check it. Quite a newbie to regex... @maxmakhrov : same comment, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Searching and testing again, I came across a variation of the =TEXT(A1,"pattern") formula : = TO_TEXT()

My final formula : 
`=REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(E20);"([0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])|([0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])|([0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])|([0-9]:[0-5][0-9])")`

I must dig a little bit to understand the difference between TO_TEXT() and TEXT()...

The issue was definitely the way you have to format the *pattern* parameter of the function. If something like 12h45 was entered, the =TEXT(E20;"hh:mm:ss") pattern would return 00:00:00, and the regex would be evaluated as TRUE.